# How do I prevent Linux from automatically timestamping recently created files?

Tags: linux, touch

To be short I would like a directory's permissions to prevent any future timestamping of new files created or edited.

In other words, is there any onetime solution that would leave a folder's contents with a fixed date stamp?

Any commands that can be used for what I intend to do?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Just some testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to disable mtime (modify) or ctime (change), which I don't think is possible.  At least not without modifying the kernel. It's common to disable atime (access) with a mount option: noatime.  But that won't give you what you desire.

See:

https://serverfault.com/questions/787940/linux-no-modify-time-nomtime/787942